# Proving an inequality consisting of sums and products

Tags: inequality, summation, products

I have a tricky inequality (related to some previous ones that I posted) which I am yet again stuck trying to solve. I have confirmed that it is true through simulation (at least up until overflow errors occur).

Let $x_j$ be a natural number greater than equal to 2, for all $j$. Define also $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N x_j$ and $\dot{x} = \prod_{j=1}^N x_j$. I would like to show that
\begin{align}
N\left(1 + \bar{x}\right)^2 \left(1 + \frac{2}{\bar{x}}\right) \leq \left(1 + \dot{x}\right)^2 \left(1 + \frac{2}{\dot{x}}\right) \; ;
\end{align}
or, equivalently,
\begin{align}
N\left(5 + 4 \bar{x} + \frac{2}{\bar{x}} + \bar{x}^2\right) \leq \left(5 + 4\dot{x} + \frac{2}{\dot{x}} + \dot{x}^2 \right) \; .
\end{align}

I'm really not sure the best approach for this. Would induction be a good approach or should a more direct approach be taken?

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Just expand. If $S=\sum x_i$, you get your inequality equivalent to $2(S/n+n/S)+S^2/n\leq 2(S+1/S)+S^2$. But $S^2/n\leq S^2$ and $x+1/x$ is increasing for $x>1$. So, $S/n+n/S\leq S+1/S$.

Comment: @NDB sorry, I’m confused how this works when we have a product of $x_j$’s?

Comment: I didn't see the product. I read both as $\sum$

Comment: But a similar analysis applies. That product, for those values, is going to be huge. So, you can compare the terms on the left and right, after expanding, in the same way. Call $S$ the sum and $P$ the product. You are going to have $2S$ on the left and $2P$ on the right. You have $S^2/n$ on the left and $P^2$ on the right. etc.

Comment: @NDB Thanks for the advice, I'll give that a go!

Comment: @NDB I think the $N$ makes things difficult for this approach. Upon expanding I get $N(5 + 4 S/N + 2N / S + (S / N)^2) \leq (5 + 4P + 2/P + P^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is straight-forward to verify that the function
$$
 f(x) = (1+x)^2 \left( 1 + \frac 2x\right)
$$
is increasing for $x \ge 2$ and also satisfies $f(2x) \ge 2f(x)$ for $x \ge 2$.

We have $\dot{x} = \prod_{j=1}^N x_j \ge 2^{N-1} \bar x$ since all factors are $\ge 2$ and at least one factor is $\ge \bar x$. It follows that
$$
 f(\dot x) \ge f(2^{N-1} \bar x) \ge 2^{N-1} f(\bar x) \ge N f(\bar x) \, ,
$$
using Bernoulli's inequality in the last step:
$$
 2^{N-1} = (1+1)^{N-1} \ge 1+(N-1) = N \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks @MartinR ! I'm just wondering about the $f(2x) \geq 2f(x)$. Have you used this anywhere?

Comment: @David: Yes, at $f(2^{N-1} \bar x) \ge 2^{N-1} f(\bar x)$.

Comment: ah we just repeatedly apply it? @MartinR

Comment: @David:  Yes, exactly.

Comment: sorry, slow day today! thanks a lot for the help, again :) Bernoulli's inequality is certainly useful!

Comment: +1, it is beautiful proof.